# Building on netty-tcnative for solaris?

Tags: netty, solaris

I have been using netty-tcnative-1.1.33.Fork17 for my web server program on solaris since 2016. (JDK1.7 32bit, netty-4.0.25, solaris11).
It is good ssl provider for me who develop java program on solaris sparc.

Then, I will update netty and netty-tcnative version on solaris sparc. 
There are many updated netty and netty-tcnative after I used.

Now, netty major version is 4.1.x ,   netty-tcnative major version is 2.0.x. I think I have to use this version.
However, over netty-tcnative 2.0.2~8 package used not supported string function(strndup) on solaris sparc in jnilib.c.

Finally, I comple and package netty-tcnative-2.0.1 with netty 4.1.13.Final on solaris sparc.(JDK1.8 64bit)

Question1. There are anyother reason not support solaris sparc after netty-tcnative-2.0.2? 
           I'm concerned about my netty-tcnative package for running. 
Question2. Can you change or include string function(strndup) on further version for solaris..?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

No there are no real reasons to not also allow to compile it on Solaris Sparc, we just not do it as part of the release process and testing. This means if there is something not working please open an issue and we will try to fix it. Or even better provide a PR with a fix. I opened

- https://github.com/netty/netty-tcnative/issues/349
- https://github.com/netty/netty-tcnative/pull/350/